# Error CS0116 - strings dump and search project

Tags: c#

i making a strings search in c# and im using strings2 to dump the strings for a process, and i have the error "namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"

```
public int pid_for_dump = 0;
private int proc_name = 0;
private int num = 0;

namespace Dax_Lite_Auto
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopWatch.Start();
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Dax Plus\assets");
            File.WriteAllBytes("assets\\s2.exe", Dax_Lite_Auto.Properties.Resources.str2);
            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
            foreach (Process process2 in Process.GetProcessesByName("s2"))
            {
                process2.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Pid_dump()
{
    Process[] processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
    if (processesByName.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("explorer not found");
    }
    string text2 = processesByName[0].StartTime.ToString();

    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("javaw"))
    {



        this.pid_for_dump = process.Id;
        this.proc_name = process.ProcessName;
        num++;
    }
    if (num == 0)
    {

    }


    else if (num > 1)
    {


    }
    else
    {

    }


    }
```

this its the errors:

Error   CS0116  in line 14
Error   CS0116  in line 15
Error   CS0116  in line 16
Error   CS0116  in line 42
Error   CS0103  in line 58
Error   CS0103  in line 60
Error   CS0103  in line 66
Error   CS0122  in line 57

please help me, im a novice in c#

Comment: isn´t the mentioned message self-explanatory? "namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods" Means you cannot have `public int pid_for_dump = 0;` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

You're trying to put fields and methods directly in the namespace, instead of in a class.

At the top of the file you have three fields *outside* of the class:

```
public int pid_for_dump = 0;
private int proc_name = 0;
private int num = 0;
```

At the bottom you have the method `Pid_dump` also *outside* of the class.

These things need to be inside a class.  Either inside the `Form2` class or another class if necessary.  (Or just remove the method and those fields entirely if nothing is using it, since nothing in the code shown uses it.)